# How to avoid null pointer in View.getDrawingCache()?

Tags: android, android-view

My app has this code snippet

```
mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getDrawingCache());
```

Where mView is an instance of a custom subclass of FrameLayout. The app has worked well for 6 months now with thousands of users. Recently I got few reports (possibly from same user but I cannot confirm) about a null pointer passed to createBitmap(). I don't know what hardware or android version the user uses.

What can cause getDrawingCache() to return null even though I enabled the cache just before it? Is it related to hardware acceleration in new phones? Is it because of insufficient ram for the bitmap? Anything else? Can it be prevented?

Edit: I found this solution [here](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6c83180248a6ff0f?pli=1). Is it a reasonable workaround?

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getWidth(), mView.getHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitMap);
mView.draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

actually your guess was right. If you are using hardware accelerated layer, you can not use drawing cache. New devices has hardware acceleration on by default, so it could be your problem. you can turn hardware acceleration off for single view like this.

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) frame.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
frame.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```